# Is there any Django project for Computer-Based Assessment Software?

Tags: python, django

I am looking for a Computer-Based Assessment application that is based on Django, but I can not find one. Does anybody know of one?

Thanks. There is none.

I will try to create one using Django. If the code is good, I will release it as GPL.

I hope to get help from the Django community here at Stackoverflow, because I am still very new with Django.

Comment: what kind of assessment? could you be more specific?

Comment: A web based platform that enables educators and trainers to author, schedule, deliver, and report on quizzes, tests and exams.

Comment: Any luck?  I'm looking for one as well.